# Functional programming in C++11, F# style

Tags: c++, c++11, f#, functional-programming

I've been looking at the new features in C++11 and it really looks like it will be possible to program in a very functional programming style using it.  I've gotten use to using the types List, Seq, Array in F# and I see no reason why their members couldn't be ported into some sort of C++11 template.  What problems or advantages do you see in using C++11 vs something like F# for a mixed functional programming style?  Maybe the Boost guys will make a new `functional` once C++11 comes out.

Comment: The reference you point to (STL Algorithm, that is not a class BTW) is about a header that is already present and standard in C++. That is, nothing new. The new C++ standard just eases the creation of the functors passed to the already existing algorithms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The biggest problem with trying to program in a functional style in C++ is that it does not support tail recursion.  In a functional language you don't have to worry about stack explosion when you tail recurse correctly, but in C++ you always have to worry about that.  Therefore, many "functional" type algorithms will be clumsy or heavy.

Comment: Not quite true. Most popular C++ compilers today will properly handle tail-recursion, although may require you to specify extra optimization flags like '-O2'.

Comment: This is true. Regardless of what a compiler may do as an optimization, the language does not provide facilities for this feature, so depending on it is dangerous.

Comment: The problem is that RAII is not compatible with tail-call optimization. The same problem exists in F# with try...finally, but it's more obvious due to the explicitness of the construct.

Comment: Not true. The compiler converts a tail call into a loop, and loops work fine with RAII. You have to exercise some judgement, but that's true of every language.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some of the problems I encountered trying to write functional code in C#, mixed with some goodies from my time when I was still using C++:

1. Lack of pattern matching. Once you get used to it, not having it can drive me crazy.
2. Lack of syntactic sugar for tuples.
3. Lack of syntax for copying records and setting fields in one go.
4. Lack of syntax for lists and arrays. That goes for constructors and pattern-matching.
5. Not having a GC, and unsafe memory accesses. Not being constrained by a GC is an advantage, but remembering the reports I got from my first runs of Valgrind on C++ code I thought was bug free scared me for ever.
6. Understanding template code isn't exactly accessible to all mortals. I don't have problem understanding mine, but whenever I looked into implementations of the STL, boost or cgal I found myself wondering what language they were using. My C++ and their C++ don't live in the same world.
7. The total lack of fun in dealing with a library that uses another version of boost (or any library that uses templates).
8. Verbosity of separate header/implementation files.
9. Type inference in C++ does not go as far as e.g. F#. I know it's been improved in C++11, but as I understand it's similar to var in C#, which isn't enough once you tasted F#-style inference.
10. Lack of computation expressions, including sequence expressions, comprehensions, async...

It would not surprise me if several of these points were actually possible in C++ using some template and preprocessor magic, but you can't really use these in a production environment unless you have very adventurous and tolerant co-workers.

I was a die-hard C++ enthusiast before. Then I started using generic programming with templates and higher-order functions using function objects. It just was too tiresome to write. After I tried a functional language I never looked back.

Answer (score 5):

You might find this interesting:

http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/linq-to-c0x/

Comment: Thanks! A starting point for a full implementation would be boost's range and iterator libraries, some combination of the two.

Answer (score 3):

> What problems of advantages do you see in using c++0x vs something like f# for a mixed functional programming style?

The [upward funarg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem#Upwards_funarg_problem), which was debated in the context of Lisp 40 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it would be… interesting… to implement certain optimizations common to functional languages in C++0x (like common subexpression elimination).

Comment: Most C and C++ compilers do CSE and GCSE.  This is not the problem.  The problem involves partial function application and tail recursion.